# Writing DecodeJson for Sealed Trait Hierarchy?

Tags: scala, argonaut

Given:

```
import argonaut._
import Argonaut._
import ArgonautShapeless._

sealed trait Parent
case class Foo(x: Int)    extends Parent
case class Bar(y: String) extends Parent
```

I attempted to define `DecodeJson[Parent]`:

```
implicit val parentDecodeJson: DecodeJson[Parent] = 
   DecodeJson(c => c.focus.objectFields match {
       case Some("x" :: _) => implicitly[DecodeJson[Foo]].decode(c)
      case _                => implicitly[DecodeJson[Bar]].decode(c)
   })
```

However, that failed since `argonaut.DecodeResult` is invariant.

```
<console>:42: error: type mismatch;
 found   : argonaut.DecodeResult[Foo]
 required: argonaut.DecodeResult[Parent]
Note: Foo <: Parent, but class DecodeResult is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
              case Some("x" :: _) => implicitly[DecodeJson[Foo]].decode(c)
                                                                       ^
<console>:43: error: type mismatch;
 found   : argonaut.DecodeResult[Bar]
 required: argonaut.DecodeResult[Parent]
Note: Bar <: Parent, but class DecodeResult is invariant in type A.
You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
             case _     => implicitly[DecodeJson[Bar]].decode(c)
                                                             ^
```

So, then I came up with:

```
implicit val parentDecodeJson: DecodeJson[Parent] = 
   DecodeJson(c => c.focus.objectFields match {
       case Some("x" :: _) => implicitly[DecodeJson[Foo]].decode(c).flatMap{a => DecodeResult.ok(a)}
      case _     => implicitly[DecodeJson[Bar]].decode(c).flatMap{a => DecodeResult.ok(a)}
   })
```

That seems to work:

```
scala> Json.obj( ("x", jNumber(42)) ).as[Parent]
res2: argonaut.DecodeResult[Parent] = DecodeResult(Right(Foo(42)))

scala> Json.obj( ("y", jString("hi!")) ).as[Parent]
res3: argonaut.DecodeResult[Parent] = DecodeResult(Right(Bar(hi!)))
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: This should work out of the box,
 at least from what the README says (https://github.com/alexarchambault/argonaut-shapeless)

Comment: how about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39108841/decoding-a-sealed-trait-in-argonaut-based-on-json-structure

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define your own implicits:

```
println(EncodeJson.of[Parent].encode(Bar("a")))//{"Bar":{"y":"a"}}
println(EncodeJson.of[Parent].apply(Bar("a")))//{"Bar":{"y":"a"}}
println(Bar("a").asJson)//{"y":"a"}
println((Bar("a"): Parent).asJson)//{"Bar":{"y":"a"}}
println("{\"Bar\":{\"y\":\"a\"}}".decode[Parent])//Right(Bar(a))
println("{\"Bar\":{\"y\":\"a\"}}".decodeOption[Parent])//Some(Bar(a))
```

Or do I misunderstand your goal?